# Is there a PingFederate metadata URL?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, pingfederate

In PingFederate, I know that we can export the metadata as a XML file, but is there an URL that I can call to access it?

OpenAM and ADFS seem to have such functionality, e.g.

- http../openam/saml2/jsp/exportmetadata.jsp?entityid=myentity
- http../FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Does PingFederate provide such functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[update 4/6/16]

PingIdentity added this functionality in 8.1:

- PingFederate publishes metadata: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/index.shtml#pf_c_connectionfederationmetadata.html
- PingFederate retrieves metadata: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/pingfederate/pf81/index.shtml#adminGuide/pf_t_manageMetadataUrls.html

Previous answer: PingFed doesn't currently have this functionality built in beyond turning on Auto-Connect. It is a current feature request.

Answer (score 1):

PingFederate version 8.0.4 also has this feature to export metadata as an IDP and also as a SP.

You can select a connection to add the attribute contract and signature.

It's in **Server Configuration -> Metadata Export**